# Error comparing cell range with cell position in Excel

Tags: excel

I am having a little problem trying to count a range of cell.

Here is my formula: =SUM(IF($E$2:$L$263=**O3**,1,0)) and I'm getting #VALUE! error.

This only works if I compare it with a number value, for example: =SUM(IF($E$2:$L$263=**1**,1,0))

Can someone enlighten me on what I did wrong or what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Oh, nvm... I've figure it out.  Forgot to convert the formula to array by Ctrl + Shift + Enter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than use SUM and IF try using COUNTIF, it's more efficient and doesn't need "array entry"

`=COUNTIF($E$2:$L$263,O3)`